# Send data without server in the middle

Tags: javascript, html

Using a browser, is it possible using client only technologies (like JS, HTML ...) to send data to another browser without going through the server that servers the HTML page?? I mean if both ends are already synchronized (one has open a port, and the other one sends the data), is it possible to do that?

Comment: The web is built on the client-server model.  Anyway you look at it, it will have to hit a server at some point.

Comment: yes but if one of the clients acts as a server? I mean if browser A can receive and send, and client B does the same (through some configuration)

Answer (score 2):

With only javascript and HTML, the answer is clearly no : you can't establish a direct P2P connection.

There are solutions involving a plugin, for example java (in the case of java, the user has to relax security, usually through signing).

But note that with [websockets](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websocket) you connect and exchange through a server but it's efficient enough for most uses (provided your users will accept [not to use IE9-](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)). WebSocket programming is easy enough those days (here's an example of [a complete chat client/server](http://gary.beagledreams.com/page/go-websocket-chat.html), googling would give an example for your favorite language) so I really recommend not to try using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requires a server. For personal projects you can try the web server plug-in for Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pow-plain-old-webserver/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a direct client-to-client transaction with JS, HTML yet, but if you check [red5](http://www.red5.org/) to uses Java frame work, it provides RTMP(Real Time Media Protocol) which for P2P connection.